# IPS Forum, Регистрация не в стандартную базу

Tags: php, mysql

В стандарте при регистрации пользователя записывает логин пасс в MySql базу а пароль еще и шифрует, нужно сделать регистрацию в отдельную MySql базу, без шифровки пароля.

```
    <?php
/**
 * @brief       External Database Login Handler
 * @author      <a href='http://www.invisionpower.com'>Invision Power Services, Inc.</a>
 * @copyright   (c) 2001 - SVN_YYYY Invision Power Services, Inc.
 * @license     http://www.invisionpower.com/legal/standards/
 * @package     IPS Social Suite
 * @since       18 Mar 2013
 * @version     SVN_VERSION_NUMBER
 */

namespace IPS\Login;

/* To prevent PHP errors (extending class does not exist) revealing path */
if ( !defined( '\IPS\SUITE_UNIQUE_KEY' ) )
{
    header( ( isset( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] ) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0' ) . ' 403 Forbidden' );
    exit;
}

/**
 * External Database Login Handler
 */
class _External extends LoginAbstract
{
    /**
     * @brief   Authentication types
     */
    public $authTypes;
    
    /**
     * Initiate
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->authTypes = $this->settings['auth_types'] ?: \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME;
    }
    
    /**
     * Authenticate
     *
     * @param   array   $values Values from from
     * @return  \IPS\Member
     * @throws  \IPS\Login\Exception
     */
    public function authenticate( $values )
    {   
        /* Build where clause */
        switch ( $this->authTypes )
        {
            case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME:
                $where = array( "{$this->settings['db_col_user']}=?", $values['auth'] );
                break;
            
            case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL:
                $where = array( "{$this->settings['db_col_email']}=?", $values['auth'] );
                break;
            
            case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME + \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL:
                $where = array( "{$this->settings['db_col_user']}=? OR {$this->settings['db_col_email']}=?", $values['auth'], $values['auth'] );
                break;
                
        }
        if ( $this->settings['db_extra'] )
        {
            $where[0] .= $this->settings['db_extra'];
        }
        
        /* Fetch result */
        try
        {
            $result = $this->externalDb()->select( '*', $this->settings['db_table'], $where )->first();
        }
        catch ( \IPS\Db\Exception $e )
        {
            throw new \IPS\Login\Exception( 'generic_error', \IPS\Login\Exception::INTERNAL_ERROR );
        }
        catch ( \UnderflowException $e )
        {
            switch ( $this->authTypes )
            {
                case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME + \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL:
                    $type = 'username_or_email';
                    break;
                    
                case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME:
                    $type = 'username';
                    break;
                    
                case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL:
                    $type = 'email_address';
                    break;
            }
            
            throw new \IPS\Login\Exception( \IPS\Member::loggedIn()->language()->addToStack( 'login_err_no_account', FALSE, array( 'sprintf' => array( \IPS\Member::loggedIn()->language()->addToStack( $type ) ) ) ), \IPS\Login\Exception::NO_ACCOUNT );
        }
        
        /* Get a local account if one exists */
        $member = NULL;
        if ( $this->settings['db_col_user'] )
        {
            $_member = \IPS\Member::load( $result[ $this->settings['db_col_user'] ], 'name' );
            if ( $_member->member_id )
            {
                $member = $_member;
            }
        }
        if ( $this->settings['db_col_email'] )
        {
            $_member = \IPS\Member::load( $result[ $this->settings['db_col_email'] ], 'email' );
            if ( $_member->member_id )
            {
                $member = $_member;
            }
        }
        
        /* If the password doesn't match, throw an exception */
        if ( !\IPS\Login::compareHashes( $this->encryptedPassword( $values['password'] ), $result[ $this->settings['db_col_pass'] ] ) )
        {
            throw new \IPS\Login\Exception( 'login_err_bad_password', \IPS\Login\Exception::BAD_PASSWORD, NULL, $member );
        }
        
        /* Or, create a member */
        if ( $member === NULL )
        {
            $member = $this->createOrUpdateAccount( NULL, array(), $this->settings['db_col_user'] ? $result[ $this->settings['db_col_user'] ] : NULL, $this->settings['db_col_email'] ? $result[ $this->settings['db_col_email'] ] : NULL );
        }
        
        /* Return */
        return $member;
    }
    
    /**
     * Encrypt Password
     *
     * @param   string  $password   The password
     * @return  bool
     */
    protected function encryptedPassword( $password )
    {
        switch ( $this->settings['db_encryption'] )
        {
            case 'md5':
                return md5( $password );
                
            case 'sha1':
                return sha1( $password );
            
            default:
                return $password;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * ACP Settings Form
     *
     * @param   string  $url    URL to redirect user to after successful submission
     * @return  array   List of settings to save - settings will be stored to core_login_handlers.login_settings DB field
     * @code
        return array( 'savekey' => new \IPS\Helpers\Form\[Type]( ... ), ... );
     * @endcode
     */
    public function acpForm()
    {
        return array(
            'login_external_conn',
            'sql_host'      =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_host', $this->settings['sql_host'] ?: 'localhost', TRUE ),
            'sql_user'      =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_user', $this->settings['sql_user'], TRUE ),
            'sql_pass'      =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_pass', $this->settings['sql_pass'], TRUE ),
            'sql_database'  =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_database', $this->settings['sql_database'], TRUE ),
            'sql_port'      =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Number( 'login_external_port', $this->settings['sql_port'], FALSE ),
            'sql_socket'    =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_socket', $this->settings['sql_socket'], FALSE ),
            'login_external_schema',
            'db_table'      =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_table', $this->settings['db_table'], TRUE ),
            'db_col_user'   =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_username', $this->settings['db_col_user'], FALSE, array(), function( $val )
                    {
                        if ( !$val and \IPS\Request::i()->login_auth_types & \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME )
                        {
                            throw new \DomainException('login_external_username_err');
                        }
                    } ),
            'db_col_email'  =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_email', $this->settings['db_col_email'], FALSE, array(), function( $val )
                    {
                        if ( !$val and \IPS\Request::i()->login_auth_types & \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL )
                        {
                            throw new \DomainException('login_external_email_err');
                        }
                    } ),
            'db_col_pass'   =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_password', $this->settings['db_col_pass'], TRUE ),
            'db_encryption' =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Select( 'login_external_encryption', $this->settings['db_encryption'], TRUE, array( 'options' => array(
                        'md5'       => 'MD5',
                        'sha1'      => 'SHA1',
                        'plaintext' => 'login_external_encryption_plain',
                    ) ) ),
            'db_extra'      =>  new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Text( 'login_external_extra', isset( $this->settings['db_extra'] ) ? $this->settings['db_extra'] : '' ),
            'login_settings',
            'auth_types'    => new \IPS\Helpers\Form\Select( 'login_auth_types', $this->settings['auth_types'], TRUE, array( 'options' => array(
                \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME => 'username',
                \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL => 'email_address',
                \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME + \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL => 'username_or_email',
            ) ) ),
        );
    }
    
    /**
     * Test Settings
     *
     * @return  bool
     * @throws  \IPS\Db\Exception
     */
    public function testSettings()
    {
        $select = array( $this->settings['db_col_pass'] );
                
        if ( $this->settings['db_col_user'] )
        {
            $select[] = $this->settings['db_col_user'];
        }
        
        if ( $this->settings['db_col_email'] )
        {
            $select[] = $this->settings['db_col_email'];
        }
        
        try
        {
            $result = $this->externalDb()->select( implode( ',', $select ), $this->settings['db_table'], $this->settings['db_extra'] )->first();
        }
        catch ( \UnderflowException $e )
        {
            // It's possible that no users exist, which is fine
        }
        
        return TRUE;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get DB Connection
     *
     * @return  bool
     * @throws  \IPS\Db\Exception
     */
    protected function externalDb()
    {
        return \IPS\Db::i( 'external_login', $this->settings );
    }
    
    /**
     * Can a member sign in with this login handler?
     * Used to ensure when a user disassociates a social login that they have some other way of logging in
     *
     * @param   \IPS\Member $member The member
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function canProcess( \IPS\Member $member )
    {
        if ( $this->authTypes & \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME and $member->name and $this->usernameIsInUse( $member->name ) )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        if ( $this->authTypes & \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL and $member->email and $this->emailIsInUse( $member->email ) )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    /**
     * Can a member change their email/password with this login handler?
     *
     * @param   string      $type   'username' or 'email' or 'password'
     * @param   \IPS\Member $member The member
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function canChange( $type, \IPS\Member $member )
    {
        return $this->canProcess( $member );
    }
        
    /**
     * Email is in use?
     * Used when registering or changing an email address to check the new one is available
     *
     * @param   string              $email      Email Address
     * @param   \IPS\Member|NULL    $exclude    Member to exclude
     * @return  bool|NULL Boolean indicates if email is in use (TRUE means is in use and thus not registerable) or NULL if this handler does not support such an API
     */
    public function emailIsInUse( $email, \IPS\Member $exclude=NULL )
    {
        if ( $exclude )
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        
        try
        {
            $this->externalDb()->select( $this->settings['db_col_email'], $this->settings['db_table'],  array( "{$this->settings['db_col_email']}=?", $email ) )->first();
            return TRUE;
        }
        catch ( \UnderflowException $e )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        catch ( \IPS\Db\Exception $e )
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Username is in use?
     * Used when registering or changing an username to check the new one is available
     *
     * @param   string  $username   Username
     * @return  bool|NULL           Boolean indicates if username is in use (TRUE means is in use and thus not registerable) or NULL if this handler does not support such an API
     */
    public function usernameIsInUse( $username )
    {
        try
        {
            $result = $this->externalDb()->select( $this->settings['db_col_user'], $this->settings['db_table'], array( "{$this->settings['db_col_user']}=?", $username ) )->first();
            return TRUE;
        }
        catch ( \UnderflowException $e )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        catch ( \IPS\Db\Exception $e )
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Change Email Address
     *
     * @param   \IPS\Member $member     The member
     * @param   string      $oldEmail   Old Email Address
     * @param   string      $newEmail   New Email Address
     * @return  void
     * @throws  \IPS\Db\Exception
     */
    public function changeEmail( \IPS\Member $member, $oldEmail, $newEmail )
    {
        if ( $this->settings['db_col_email'] )
        {
            $this->externalDb()->update( $this->settings['db_table'], array( $this->settings['db_col_email'] => $newEmail ), array( $this->settings['db_col_email'] . '=?', $oldEmail ) );
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Change Password
     *
     * @param   \IPS\Member $member         The member
     * @param   string      $newPassword    New Password
     * @return  void
     * @throws  \IPS\Db\Exception
     */
    public function changePassword( \IPS\Member $member, $newPassword )
    {
        $where = '1=0';
        switch ( $this->authTypes )
        {
            case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME:
                $where = array( "{$this->settings['db_col_user']}=?", $member->name );
                break;
            
            case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL:
            case \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_USERNAME + \IPS\Login::AUTH_TYPE_EMAIL:
                $where = array( "{$this->settings['db_col_email']}=?", $member->email );
                break;
            
                
        }
        
        $this->externalDb()->update( $this->settings['db_table'], array( $this->settings['db_col_pass'] => $this->encryptedPassword( $newPassword ) ), $where );
    }
    
    /**
     * Change Username
     *
     * @param   \IPS\Member $member         The member
     * @param   string      $oldUsername    Old Username
     * @param   string      $newUsername    New Username
     * @return  void
     * @throws  \IPS\Db\Exception
     */
    public function changeUsername( \IPS\Member $member, $oldUsername, $newUsername )
    {
        if ( $this->settings['db_col_user'] )
        {
            $this->externalDb()->update( $this->settings['db_table'], array( $this->settings['db_col_user'] => $newUsername ), array( $this->settings['db_col_user'] . '=?', $oldUsername ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем хранить пароль в открытом виде?

Comment: Так как MsSql и файлы работающие с ним воспринимают только Binary и Varchar,в стандарте есть инструменты для дублирования